# Django admin csrf token not set

Tags: python, django, nginx, csrf

I have a Django project working locally with login to the admin portal working. Once the project has been deployed to our development environment the pages that do not require CSRF authentication are viewable, but the admin portal returns a CSRF token error when attempting to login.
Error received: `CSRF cookie not set`
The project is meant to be deployed to a subdomain (ie https://project.myapp.com) with the development/staging version deployed to a different subdomain (https://project.dev.myapp.com).

Subset of the settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_object_actions',
]

MIDDLEWARE = (
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Originally I assumed that the issue was due to the project being deployed on a subdomain and followed the documentation for [csrf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/csrf/) and added the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://*.myapp.com']` to the settings but the issue persists.

I also tried setting the `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` setting to either `.myapp.com` or to `.dev.myapp.com` but continue to see the same issue.

I had also seen people mention the `django.template.context_processors.csrf`  option to add to the TEMPLATES context_processors and tried that, but this also had no effect.

When looking at the request to the /admin/login view, a `csrfmiddlewaretoken` is included, but nothing is being set in the browser.

Is there a different setting I'm missing?

P.S.
The deployment is run with uwsgi behind nginx but since the pages are all still served properly I'm (maybe incorrectly) assuming the issue doesn't lie there.

**Edit:**
Adding the NGINX config files being used - im not very well versed in NGINX but I don't believe anything would be stripping the cookie header.

nginx.conf

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /dev/stderr warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$realip_remote_addr [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent $request_time '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                    '"$http_x_amzn_trace_id" "$http_x_amz_cf_id"';

    access_log /dev/stdout main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    #maximum file size
    client_max_body_size 0;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

server.conf

```
upstream myapp {
  server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
  listen 7999 default_server;
  server_name $GENERAL_SUBDOMAIN.$GENERAL_DOMAIN;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.params;

  # Enable RealIP
  real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;
  real_ip_recursive   on;
  set_real_ip_from    0.0.0.0/0;
  uninitialized_variable_warn off;


  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  location /static/admin {
    uwsgi_pass myapp;
    include uwsgi_params;

    uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 600;
    uwsgi_ignore_client_abort on;

    expires $static_expires;
  }

  location /static {
    root /app;
    expires $static_expires;
  }

  location / {
    uwsgi_pass myapp;
    include uwsgi_params;

    uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 600;
    uwsgi_ignore_client_abort on;

    expires $static_expires;
  }
}
# vim: ft=nginx ts=2 sw=2
```

myapp.params

```
error_page 497 https://$best_http_host:$server_port$request_uri;

# vim: ft=nginx ts=2 sw=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could make `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` and `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` flags are matching. You've set `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False`. If `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` is True, then it might be causing the issue. You should either set both flags to be False during development or set them both True for a production HTTPS environment.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```

For CSRF Cookie Domain, when you move to a new subdomain, the period `.` at the start is crucial. This ensures all sub-domains are included.

```
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.myapp.com'
```

And, it might be beneficial to ensure that your NGINX configuration isn't stripping out the "Cookie" header for some reason. The CSRF Token mechanism in Django works by comparing a value stored in your session cookie to a value sent in a hidden form field or HTTP header. If your NGINX configuration isn't properly forwarding along the Cookie header, this could cause the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've updated the post to include the NGINX config files. I don't believe there's anything in there that would be removing the cookie header. The `SESSION_COOKIES_SECURE` setting was not being used before, but according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-secure) it should be defaulting to False so the two settings should match.

Comment: Maybe you could try to log the cookie in the Nginx access log and see what exact parameters Ngixn pass to Django. 

```
log_format custom '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                  '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                  '"$http_x_real_ip" "$http_cookie"';

server {
    ...
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log custom;
    ...
}
```